# Different between firebase realtime database and firebase firestore

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore, android-studio-3.0

I am working on an android application that is based on IQ level questions. That I wanted to upload on the play store. The app consisted of levels more than 50. each level is consist of 9 questions. I am confused about which database I will use for my app.

Comment: See the question I linked, but also have a look at the documentation on choosing between the databases: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/rtdb-vs-firestore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the Firebase Docs:

**Firebase Realtime Database**

The Firebase Realtime Database is a cloud-hosted database. Data is stored as JSON and synchronized in real-time to every connected client. When you build cross-platform apps with our Apple platforms, Android, and JavaScript SDKs, all of your clients share one Realtime Database instance and automatically receive updates with the newest data.

**Cloud Firestore**

Cloud Firestore is a flexible, scalable database for mobile, web, and server development from Firebase and Google Cloud. Like Firebase Realtime Database, it keeps your data in sync across client apps through real-time listeners and offers offline support for mobile and web so you can build responsive apps that work regardless of network latency or Internet connectivity. Cloud Firestore also offers seamless integration with other Firebase and Google Cloud products, including Cloud Functions.

[Firebase Docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/)